# how tp find a polynomial when the leading coefficient and some remainder are given?

Tags: polynomials

> The leading coefficient of a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $3$ is $2006$.
>   Suppose that $P(1)=5$, $P(2)=7$ and $P(3)=9$, then find $P(x)$.
>
> $(1)\ \ 2006(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+2x+3$
>
> $(2)\ \ 2006(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+2x+1$
>
> $(3)\ \ 2006(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+2x-1$
>
> $(4)\ \ 2006(x-2)(x-3)(x-1)-(2x-3)$

at all i didn't even understand this question.. please tell me

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that we have to find an answer from the four possible choices given. In all of the answer choices, the leading coefficient is 2006, so we no longer need to worry about that condition.  Now, we must ensure that the function $P(x)$ yields its prescribed values.  We notice that in all cases, the first product vanishes when we plug in $x=1,2,3$.  So we simply need to worry about the second summand.  We have that $P(1) = 5$, $P(2)=7$, and $P(3)=9$ exactly when the second summand is $2x+3$.  Thus the answer is $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=1$ in those options... Only one will be suited for $P(1)=5$

Comment: Especially if you find a question like this on a timed examination, you do not want to waste time evaluating all the polynomials at all the given values of $x.$ Instead, eliminate each choice as quickly as possible. This answer is a good way to do that. (Indeed _any_ of the three values of $x$ will work. The important part of this answer is that one value is enough. That is what makes this a good answer.)

Comment: @DavidK : Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a MCQ question find the polynomial for which $P(1)=5$, $P(2)=7$ and $P(3)=9$ are satisfied.